# Unexpected results from query

Tags: api, openfda

If I check the FDA's Drug Shortage page the first item on the list is a product with a generic name of: Abciximab (ReoPro) Injection.  If I click on the link provided there is a column called presentation that shows an NDC number of 57894-200-01.  If I query the FDA's api with the following query I get no matches found.

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=package_ndc:"57894-200-01"&limit=1
```

If I download the FDA's NDC directory from https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/ndc/download/ and search the text for 57894-200-01 I do get a result and 57894-200-01 is a valid package ndc number.  Why am I getting "no matches found" on my query?

Comment: There were two identical queries in your text, I have edited one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason why the first uri doesn't find the product is that the product_ndc is 57894-200, not 57894-200-01.

So, https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_ndc:%2257894-200%22 returns product data.

It seems unclear to me how to structure the second query.

Best regards.